# Apache reverse proxy sending fewer bytes than backend web server

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm troubleshooting an issue where users report that certain images don't load on the site. When we go to the same page, the images load fine.

I've narrowed the issue down to the front/reverse proxy server sending out a different number of bytes from the back/web server. Both servers are running `Apache 2.4.6 (CentOS)`.

Logs from the web server, showing that 560828 bytes were returned to the reverse proxy.

```
170.212.0.91 - - [08/Mar/2021:18:18:00 -0500] "GET /admin/study/396/textMessage/6573554/image/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 560828 "https://app.waytohealth.org/epic/embed/469567986" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0)" 967316us YEawqCLinOEsvxlNLHpmUgAAABk
```

Logs from the front (reverse proxy) server, showing that 335872 bytes were sent back to the client.

```
170.212.0.91 - - [08/Mar/2021:18:18:00 -0500] "GET /admin/study/396/textMessage/6573554/image/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 335872 "https://app.waytohealth.org/epic/embed/469567986" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0)"
```

Potentially relevant: The users having issues are accessing through a complex embedded IE thing in a Citrix app. This usually works (despite occasional IE compatibility bugs with new features... sigh...) but does mean that there might be a weird network thing causing it to e.g. hang up mid-request.

There is nothing in the httpd error logs at the time point in question.

What are my next steps to debug this? The only thing I can think of is to [add %O to the logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_logio.html).

Comment: it is possible to have reverse proxy send less bytes to client -- there's `Content-Encoding: gzip` anyway. It is also returning HTTP 200. Ask your clients to send you [HAR](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) captures.

Comment: This isn't just a gzip thing. The client loaded ~8 images; for 2 of them both servers sent the same number of bytes, and for the rest the front server sent about half as many bytes. When I went to try to reproduce, the front server sent the expected number of bytes.

Comment: HAR captures is an interesting idea, but due to the nature of the clients (embedded IE in a larger Citrix app) I don't see how I can do that. I'll need to see if there's some similar way to inspect network traffic.

Comment: try [`mod_dumpio`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html). Note that it'll dump a huge amount of trace logs, so probably do it with care.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Do you know if there's a way to conditionally enable it (e.g. only for requests matching a certain regex)?